# online judge problems program c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, array-algorithms

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int TMAX = 2000000;

int num_chupiguays(const int a[], int n) {
    int suma  = 0;
    int resul = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i > 0 && a[i] % suma == 0) {
            resul++;
        } --> gives an run error in an online judge
/*if (i > 0 && suma != 0 &&  a[i] % suma == 0) {
            resul++;
        }*/ --> gives a wrong answer
        suma += a[i];
    }
    return resul;
}

void lee_vector(int a[], int& n) {
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    static int a[TMAX];
    int n;
    do {
        lee_vector(a, n);
        if (n >= 0) {
            cout << num_chupiguays(a, n) << endl;
        }
    } while (n != -1);
}
```

The program counts how many numbers in the array are multiples of the sum of previous elements. It passes all cases but I keep getting run-error in an online judge. Any help?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256631/discussion-on-question-by-ola-online-judge-problems-program-c); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The program counts how many numbers in the array are multiples of the sum of previous elements. It passes all cases but I keep getting run-error in an online judge. Any help?

Break the test into two parts. The first test is a special case that was identified in the problem description:

> Note that the only int that is a multiple of 0 is 0 itself.

So long as variable `suma` remains at `0`, you have a special case. Note that the value of loop counter `i` is irrelevant to this test.

```cpp
if (suma == 0)
{
    if (a[i] == 0)
        ++resul;
}
```

Otherwise, the second test uses the mod operator to check whether `a[i]` leaves a remainder after division by `suma`:

```cpp
if (suma == 0)
{
    if (a[i] == 0)
        ++resul;
}
else if (a[i] % suma == 0)
{
    ++resul;
}
```

Dropping these tests into the function written by the OP, while keeping everything else the same, gives you this function:

```cpp
int num_chupiguays(const int a[], int n)
{
    int suma = 0;
    int resul = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (suma == 0)
        {
            if (a[i] == 0)
                ++resul;
        }
        else if (a[i] % suma == 0)
        {
            ++resul;
        }
        suma += a[i];
    }
    return resul;
}
```

Here is the output from several test runs. The last two are the "problem" tests that were identified in the comments. Happily, they are now behaving:

```
array: [], num_chupiguays: 0
array: [0], num_chupiguays: 1
array: [1], num_chupiguays: 0
array: [1,2], num_chupiguays: 1
array: [2,3,5], num_chupiguays: 1
array: [2,4,7,26,5], num_chupiguays: 2
array: [1,1,1,6,2,44], num_chupiguays: 3
```